# PL/SQL Consultar el valor de una columna que finaliza con '_' o '%'

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta tabla con valores random y quiero seleccionar únicamente las que terminan con "_" o "%" en la columna sabor haciendo uso de la opcion "ESCAPE".

he tratado de esta manera pero así me trae también las que tienen "_" en medio del valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si intento de ésta manera no me regresa ninguna fila.

```
select * from bonyurt where sabor like '%\_' escape '\'
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: He estado probando, y [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9515b/13) aqui funciona. A ver si va ha ser un tema de versiones.

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo asi:

```
   select * from bonyurt where sabor like '%/_' escape '/'
```

Espero te sirva!

Answer (score -1):

para poder obtener el resultado de una consulta que cumpla una u otra condición hay que usar el operador OR.

Aplicando lo mencionado a tu pregunta la consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
select * from bonyurt where sabor like '%/_' escape '/' OR sabor like '%/%'  escape '/';
```

Otra alternativa sería consultar cada filtro por separado y luego unir ambos resultados con el operador UNION ALL

```
select * from bonyurt where sabor like '%/_' escape '/'
union all
select * from bonyurt where sabor like '%/%'  escape '/';
```

Espero te sirva.